# Any Plone product for counting file downloads and pages view?

Tags: statistics, plone, intranet

I'm doing an intranet which will not be accessible from outside the company's network and they want to display in Plone some nice statistics about file downloads and pages most viewed.

With the network constrain I can not use google analytics or any sort of external service, so is there any product that allows to count file downloads and pages viewed?

I've seen an [idea on uservoice](http://plone.uservoice.com/forums/20503-plone-improvement-ideas/suggestions/1385121-view-download-counter) regarding file downloads, and maybe I could extend [plone.piwik.now](http://plone.org/products/collective.piwik.now) to get page view statistics but I have a hard time thinking that Plone doesn't have any product that (maybe partially) suits this use case.

Any tip?

Answer (score 2):

Essentially, you've two options, you can use one of the existing HTTP log analysis tools and scrape the information you need from those reports, or you can write a custom analytics tool in Plone.

We're currently working on a version which we plan to release as open source later this year. Essentially the patterns we're using is that we have a small javascript which passes parameters to our lightweight logging app.  We're than able to show results from the reporting app like "top downloads" in portlets, even filtering by section and keyword.

Comment: Wow, that's what I was actually thinking of doing also, but it's going to be delayed, our client changed their needs. I'm really interested on it though, let me know when you release it as open source!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about Plone add-ons (nor do I understand why you'd want to use a Plone add-on to do this) but [Webalizer](http://www.webalizer.org/) and/or http://awstats.sourceforge.net/ are two of the most popular choices.

Comment: The two programs aclark mentions are log-analysis programs. Plone keeps standard web logs, and if you're using a reverse proxy, it probably does also. Log analysis is easy and is much lighter in overhead than updating your database for every read.

Comment: Sure log analysis programs do, but then I still need to plug does programs to Plone, since my question was about to display that information on Plone itself, e.g. a section on the main page showing the top downloaded files or the most viewed files from a given content type.